# Como preencher formulário a partir da combobox, com informação da base de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, combobox, textbox

Usei o código assim:

```
<html lang="pt-pt">

<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "isabelso_isabel";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "isabelso_db";

$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

$query = "SELECT nome FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>

<form name="medicos" method="post" action="">
<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um Medico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos">
    <option>Selecione...</option>

    <?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$prod['nome'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>    
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtMedico" value="" />
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("cbMedicos").addEventListener("change", function () 
{
    document.getElementById("txtMedico").value = this.value;
});
</script>
```

Mas quando ponho a correr, dá este erro: "/teste.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Quando você executa, retorna algum tipo de erro?

Comment: @inovapixel a página fica em branco

Comment: Você inseriu as credenciais de conexão ao banco? Eu não vejo problemas no código.

Comment: @inovapixel A nível da página em branco já resolvi, foi um erro meu noutra parte do código... mas agora nesta parte: não está a fazer nada! com o código como está, quando seleciono um nome da combobox já deveria passar o nome, para a textbox "nome", certo?

Comment: Certamente não devia, e não vai sem que haja código _javascript_ que o faça no evento `onchange` da combobox. Esta não possui nem um id, de modo que dificilmente deve ter o evento armado...

Comment: Você quer passar o valor de select para um input tipo text? Se for isso, você precisará usar javascript

Comment: @inovapixel Eu quero que ao selecionar um nome da combobox passe todos os dados que estão na base de dados associados aquele nome para as respetivas textboxs de modo a depois puder apagar ou editar...

Comment: @wtrmute nunca usei javascript, assim como php é a primeira vez... Será possível exemplificar?

Comment: O que você quer fazer é mais complexo; requer um novo algoritmo. Se você não entende de javascript e php, seria um tanto complicado fazer. Isso requer bem mais linhas do que essas aí. Não tenho como exemplificar aqui, estou sem tempo. Vim aqui para ver se uma pergunta minha já tem resposta; desculpe, Isabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o usuário seleciona um elemento da combobox, é uma atividade que ocorre no lado do cliente (isto é, do navegador), e o código que executa no servidor, o PHP, não tem e nem pode ter ciência de quando isso acontece.

Portanto, precisamos de código que execute no cliente, isto é, *javascript*, que vai tratar este assunto. Digamos que o código que cria a combobox e a caixa de texto estão abaixo:

```
$query = "SELECT nome FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>
<form name="medicos" method="post" action="administrador_medicos_populate.php">
    <label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um Medico</label>
    <select id="cbMedicos">
        <option>Selecione...</option>

        <?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$prod['nome'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>    
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="txtMedico" value="" />
```

Precisamos prosseguir com um código que pegue o valor da combobox `cbMedicos` e o ponha na caixa de texto `txtMedico`, quando aquela mudar. Para tanto, precisamos de uma *tag* `<script>`.

Ordinariamente, eu diria para pôr as *tags* `<script>` dentro da *tag* `<head>`, mas aí precisaríamos escutar um segundo evento para esperar que a página tenha sido criada antes de amarrar o evento na `cbMedicos`; então ponha o seguinte código na sua página nalgum ponto *depois* de onde você define `cbMedicos`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("cbMedicos").addEventListener("change", function () {
        document.getElementById("txtMedico").value = this.value;
    });
</script>
```

Este código obtém uma referência à combobox através do seu id usando `getElementById()`, e adiciona um evento usando [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) para o evento `change`. Quando o valor da combobox mudar, ele vai executar essa função que é o segundo parâmetro da `addEventListener()`.

Dentro da função, o ponteiro `this` aponta para a própria combobox, então obtemos uma referência à caixa de texto usando o mesmo `document.getElementById()` e atribuímos ao seu valor o valor da combobox (propriedade `.value`).

Adapte o código aqui à sua situação e veja se funciona.

#### Para trazer várias informações:

Se você quer trazer várias informações de vários médicos, existem muitas opções, mas possivelmente o ideal é serializar as suas informações para JSON usando `json_serialize()` e atribuir a uma variável javascript, que o evento de `onchange` da combobox vai usar para popular todos os outros controles:

```
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "isabelso_isabel";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "isabelso_db";

$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

// vamos dar um alias para cada coluna conforme o nome do 
$query = "SELECT nome as txtNome, email as txtEmail /*, etc. */ FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       
$meujson = array();

?>

<form name="medicos" method="post" action="">
<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um Medico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos">
    <option>Selecione...</option>

    <?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtNome'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';
        $meujson[$prod['txtNome']] = $prod; // coleciona as linhas no $meujson
    }
    ?>    
</select>
<label for="txtNome">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtNome" value="" />
<label for="txtNome">Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" />
<!-- etc. -->
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// Armazenar a coleção de dados (chaveada por nome) numa variável javascript
var dados = <?php echo json_encode($meujson); ?>;
document.getElementById("cbMedicos").addEventListener("change", function () 
{
    // obtém a linha referente ao médico selecionado
    var linha = dados[this.value];
    // a forma "for (<variável> in <objeto>) itera sobre as chaves
    // (nomes de propriedades) do objeto mencionado,
    // e põe cada uma na variável de índice por vez
    for (var ch in linha) {
        (document.getElementById(ch) || {}).value = linha[ch];
    }
});
</script>
```

Ou seja, estou criando no PHP um `array()` que vou usar como dicionário para coletar todas as informações de todos os médicos, chaveadas pelo nome do profissional (poderia ser pelo id da tabela, neste caso teríamos que trazê-lo também do banco).

Depois disso, no `<script>`, criamos uma variável que vai armazenar essas informações todas. Para tanto, escrevemos as informações que coletamos como JSON (notação de objeto do javascript, na sigla em inglês) que é convenientemente a sintaxe de criação de literais de objeto no javascript. Assim, `dados` é uma variável que contém todas as informações que vamos precisar preencher para cada médico — só tome cuidado para que não haja médicos nem informação demais, senão a página vai ficar pesada. Se ficar, vamos ter que trocar de estratégia e trazer as informações assincronamente usando AJAX, provavelmente.

Finalmente, no evento `change` da combobox, pegamos o elemento do objeto `dados` que corresponde ao médico selecionado (lembre-se que `$meujson` e portanto `dados` é um dicionário cujas chaves são os nomes dos médicos) e iteramos sobre as chaves deste documento, que de propósito são os IDs dos controles que devem ser preenchidos por eles, assinalando cada um por sua vez.

Dois detalhes:

- Primeiro, a forma `for (`*variável*`in`*objeto*`)` itera sobre as **chaves**, não sobre os **valores** de *objeto*. Então, você ainda tem que desreferenciar o objeto para obter o valor correspondente à chave (usando o operador de índice `[]`, igualzinho aos arrays de PHP).

  Por exemplo, se você tiver um objeto `obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };` e você disser `for (var i in obj) { alert(i); }`, vão aparecer duas *popups* de mensagem, uma dizendo "a" e a outra "b". Para obtermos o "1" e o "2", teríamos que dizer `for (var i in obj) { alert(obj[i]); }`.
- Segundo, a brincadeira de `(`*objeto*`|| {})` é um truque semelhante ao `or die()` do PHP: se a `document.getElementById(ch)` falhar, por não existir um controle com um ID igual à chave em questão, ela retorna um valor `null`; se tentássemos atribuir algo à propriedade `value` de `null` tomaríamos um erro e a execução do *script* pararia. No entanto, como `null` equivale a falso, aplicamos um operador `or` (que em javascript se escreve `||`) e um objeto vazio `{}`.

  Assim, se um controle com um determinado id não existir, `document.getElementById(ch)` retorna `null`, mas `(document.getElementById(ch) || {})` retorna `{}`, que é um objeto vazio, e a propriedade vai ser atribuída a ele e depois ele vai ser descartado e coletado pelo coletor de lixo, sem levantar erro.

Comment: editei a minha pergunta inicial com o código que usei agora

Comment: Agora, o código 404 simplesmente diz que você pôs o arquivo PHP no lugar errado, porque o servidor não o encontrou. Não diz nada sobre se o cóidgo PHP/HTML/javascript está correto ou não; de fato, ele não o encontrou para tentar!

Comment: É possível agora através deste código colocar nos inputs type text todos os dados da base de dados associados aquele nome?

Comment: Por exemplo se alterar a query, e selecionar os vários atributos que pretendo retirar da base de dados e depois alterar o script no  document.getElementById("txtnome").value, é suficiente? Ficar, por exemplo:  document.getElementById("txtnome", "txtemail").value...

Comment: @IsabelSousa: Não; `document.getElementById()` recebe um único id e retorna  a referência a um único elemento. Se você quer armazenar várias informações, vai ter que armazenar usando outra estratégia, como armazenar os dados como um objeto javascript (JSON) numa variável e depois alterá-la. Vou adicionar uma seção à resposta com uma possibilidade.

Comment: É isso mesmo, está perfeito....